# my colliderect isnt working

Tags: python, pygame

so i wrote small game where you have to dodge things but then i saw colliderect function and i wantet to change hard coded collusion with simply colliderect code. i set it up but it didnt wokred so i tested it and created new pygame file!

```
import pygame
w=400;h=400
pygame.init()
root=pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
pygame.display.set_caption('TEST SUBJECT')
def gameloop():
    thing=pygame.image.load('unnamed.png')
    th=thing.get_rect()
    thing2=pygame.image.load('s.png')
    th2=thing2.get_rect()
    clock=pygame.time.Clock()
    while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            root.blit(thing,(w//2-50,h//2-60))
            root.blit(thing2,(0,0))
        if th.colliderect(th2)==1:
            print('OK')
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)
gameloop()
```

as you can say here colliderect returns 1 even tho two object doesnt hit each other.

Comment: they hit each other because you don't change `th` and `th2`. It doesn't matter that you display it in different places. Try `root.blit(thing, th)` and `root.blit(thing, th2)` and you see that they collide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They hit each other because you don't change `th` and `th2`.

It doesn't matter that you display it in different places.

Try

```
 root.blit(thing, th) 
 root.blit(thing, th2)
```

and you see that they collide.

You have to change `th.x`, `th.y` or `th2.x`, `th.y` to change position and then `th.colliderect(th2)` will work.

---

**EDIT:** full working example

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

WIDTH = 400
HEIGHT = 400

BLACK = ( 0, 0, 0)

FPS = 25

# --- main --- (lower_case names)

# - init -

pygame.init()

root = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
root_rect = root.get_rect()

# - objects -

thing1 = pygame.image.load('ball-1.png')
thing1_rect = thing.get_rect()

thing2 = pygame.image.load('ball-2.png')
thing2_rect = thing2.get_rect()

# move things
thing1_rect.left = root_rect.left
thing1_rect.centery = root_rect.centery

thing2_rect.right = root_rect.right
thing2_rect.centery = root_rect.centery

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    # - updates (without draws) -

    # move objects
    thing1_rect.x += 5
    thing2_rect.x -= 5

    # check collisions
    if thing1_rect.colliderect(thing2_rect):
        print('Collision')

    # - draws (without updates) -

    root.fill(BLACK)
    root.blit(thing1, thing1_rect)
    root.blit(thing2, thing2_rect)

    pygame.display.update()

    # - FPS -

    clock.tick(FPS)
```

ball-1.png

[image]

ball-2.png

[image]

Comment: you use `(w//2-50,h//2-60)` and `(0,0)` to display images and they don't touch on screen but you use values from `th` and `th2` to check collision which are `(0,0)` and `(0,0)` so they collide. Use only  `th` and `th2` to display, check collision and change position.